# How to use macOS audio work groups with an AudioServerPlugin

Tags: multithreading, macos, audio, core-audio, driverkit

I have a USB driver for a soundcard that is built using DriverKit and a AudioServerPlugin that enables macOS to use the soundcard for audio input and output.

The AudioServerPlugin works fine using Apple Silicon, except when using a computer with a M1 Max or M1 Pro processor, when there are audible click and pops. My suspicion is that this is related to thread priority.

The driver completes `OSAction` objects to signal to the AudioServerPlugin that some buffer is ready to be consumed by the AudioServerPlugin. The `OSAction` objects are queued up by the AudioServerPlugin using `IOConnectCallAsyncMethod`. The AudioServerPlugin has a thread that consumes the completed event and then reads from the completed buffer, and then writes the audio data to buffers that are available to Core Audio.

I have read up on [audio work groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/workgroup_management/understanding_audio_workgroups/). I wonder if I should implement something related to this, and how to do that.

Most examples around this is when a program reads or writes to a device. One can for example query the work group of a device with `kAudioDevicePropertyIOThreadOSWorkgroup`.
I've added this property to the AudioServerPlugin, but I can't see that anyone is asking for it. Should Core Audio ask for it, or is that only a property that is asked by user apps?

Comment: I'm pretty sure workgroups are for CoreAudio clients (apps), not CoreAudio plugins, like yours. You need to carefully trace your driver without making the dropouts worse to find where you're missing a deadline. Maybe your IPC method (`OSAction`) is not realtime enough and a shared memory buffer would be better? And speaking of IPC bureaucracy, why have an ASP + DriverKit driver at all when you could have a single AudioDriverKit driver that does everything?

Comment: Driverkit is available from Big Sur, but AudiodriverKit is only available from Monterey, that is why we need the AudioServerPlugin.

Comment: Ok - maybe driver is occasionally falling behind - does increasing `kAudioDevicePropertySafetyOffset` help?